# Weird WHERE Clause Behavior. Why does this return a row?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, why does this return the row, even when I add a whitespace, or two, or more, to the end of the where clause? shouldn't zero records be found in the following example?

```
WITH SRC AS (SELECT cast('12345' as varchar) DEMO)
SELECT * FROM SRC WHERE DEMO='12345  '
```

What if one needs to query to find `'1234 '` but not `'1234'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is happening is that SQL pads spaces to the end of strings so that they are of the same length. So if you try do something like:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '' = ' '
```

You will actually get 1 back even though they are not the same. However, if you do something like:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' = ' a'
```

It will not return anything as it would be comparing 'a ' to ' a' which do not match.

However, this would return 1:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'a' = 'a '
```

As it is comparing 'a ' to 'a '

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this behavior is according to the ANSI SQL-92 standard (section 8.2, rule 3), so you can expect all compliant DMBS to work the same way.  SQL Server specifically behaves differently for LIKE comparison, concatenation, and storage of the value depending on the ANSI_NULLS setting.  Here's a summary of the behavior: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63953/

Comment: @ChrisBergin: This is only an option of the collation in Standard SQL (defaults to `PAD SPACE`), but a DBMS might also implement `NO PAD`, e.g. Oracle and PostgreSQL work as the OP expected.

Comment: All makes sense. SO, What if one needs to query to find `'1234 ' ` but not `'1234`?

Comment: @robarwebservices: In Standard SQL `LIKE` always uses `NO PAD`, so this will work: `col LIKE '1234  '`. But afaik SQL Server does not work correct, just MySQL. I tried a fiddle, (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aff35c), but it's down again. This should always work: `col = '1234 ' AND CHAR_LENGTH(col) = 5`

Comment: @dnoeth [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx): "Unicode LIKE is compatible with the ISO standard. ASCII LIKE is compatible with earlier versions of SQL Server."

Answer (score 7):

> What if one needs to query to find '1234 ' but not '1234'

If you are using Unicode data, you can simply use `LIKE`. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> > When all arguments (*match_expression, pattern, and escape_character*, if present) are ASCII character data types, ASCII pattern matching is performed. If any one of the arguments are of Unicode data type, all arguments are converted to Unicode and Unicode pattern matching is performed. When you use Unicode data (**nchar** or **nvarchar** data types) with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant; however, for non-Unicode data, trailing blanks are not significant. Unicode LIKE is compatible with the ISO standard. ASCII LIKE is compatible with earlier versions of SQL Server.

With non-Unicode data, you can get still get Unicode `LIKE` behaviour, at the cost of some implicit conversions (note the `LIKE` pattern in the second query has a leading 'N', denoting a Unicode string literal):

```
DECLARE @T AS table 
(
    pk integer IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    v varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (v, pk)
);

INSERT @T (v) 
VALUES 
    ('1234'), 
    ('1234' + SPACE(1)),
    ('1234' + SPACE(2)),
    ('1234' + SPACE(3));

SELECT REPLACE(T.v, SPACE(1), '@')
FROM @T AS T 
WHERE T.v LIKE '1234 ';

SELECT REPLACE(T.v, SPACE(1), '@')
FROM @T AS T 
WHERE T.v LIKE N'1234 ';
```

Results:

[image: Results]

The code with the implicit conversion may still be able to use an index, through the magic of [dynamic seek generation](https://sql.kiwi/2012/01/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.html):

[image: Plan]

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the following portion of the Question:

> What if one needs to query to find '1234 ' but not '1234'

It seems that using a binary Collation (i.e. one ending in `_BIN2`) does not work for this, but you can additionally compare the `DATALENGTH` of the two values:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @T (Col1) VALUES ('12345  ');
INSERT INTO @T (Col1) VALUES ('12345');

SELECT DATALENGTH(Col1) AS [Col1Bytes], '~' + Col1 + '~' AS [Col1] FROM @T;

SELECT DATALENGTH(Col1) AS [Col1Bytes], '~' + Col1 + '~' AS [Col1] FROM @T
WHERE Col1 = '12345  '
AND   DATALENGTH(Col1) = DATALENGTH('12345  ');
```

Returns:

```
Col1Bytes    Col1
7            ~12345  ~
5            ~12345~

Col1Bytes    Col1
7            ~12345  ~
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to [srutzky's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138813/37243) to the "what if" portion of the question:

> What if one needs to query to find '1234 ' but not '1234'

Just make sure the last characters of what you're comparing aren't white-space.

```
SELECT      *
FROM        (
                            SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'1234 ') AS TestVal
                UNION ALL   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'1234')
            ) AS TestTable
WHERE       TestTable.TestVal = '1234 '
AND         TestTable.TestVal + '.' = '1234 ' + '.';
```

It's best to keep both conditions in the WHERE clause (the direct comparison and calculated comparison) to preserve index use.